# Using preg_replace to replace chords but not chorus and bridge

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have some text that looks like this:

```
[Verse 1]
[B]This is a song with chords [D]and lyrics
Blah [Am7+9d]blah blah [C]blah blah

[Verse 2]
This [C]is the verse
This is the [G]verse

[Chorus]
This is [E#]the Chorus
This is the Chorus

[Bridge]
This is [F]the bridge
This is [Am]the bridge
```

I want to replace all the chords ([A],[Am], [A#], [B], [C] etc all the way to [G]) so I can just show the lyrics.

Here is my current code that almost works:

```
$line = preg_replace('~\[([A-G].*?)\]~', '', $line);
```

This works prefect but it removes [Chorus] and [Bridge] because they start with C and B.

How do I still make it work perfectly but not remove the [Chorus] and the [Bridge]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$line = preg_replace('~\[(?!Chorus|Bridge)[A-G].*?\]~', '', $line);`

Comment: It may be sensible to ignore case in case of occurrences of [chorus] etc:
$line = preg_replace('~\[(?!Chorus|Bridge)[A-G].*?\]~i', '', $line);

Comment: what about Am7 or F# or Asus7 or Am7+9d?

Answer (score 0):

A different (and more generic) solution, based on assumptions about your data derived from the text snippet provided.

```
if (preg_match("/^\[[^\[\]]*\]$/", $line) === 0)
    $line = preg_replace("/\[.*\]/", "", $line);
```